# How to check the string has number and special characters in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js

I have the below function to find the string contains numbers and special characters, but it was not working

```
let validateStr = (stringToValidate) => {
var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;
if (stringToValidate&& stringToValidate.length > 2 && pattern.test(stringToValidate)) 
    {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
};
validateStr("123$%^$") // I need the above function should return false.
validateStr("sdsdsdsd$%^$") // true
validateStr("sdsdsdsd") // true
validateStr("sdsdsdsd45678") // false
validateStr("$#*()%^$")//false
validateStr("123434333")//false
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Special character validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667329/special-character-validation)

Comment: @Najamussaqib this is not duplicate, check the 4th function call, it was not working in your case .validateStr("$#*()%^$") check it with ur pattern.

Comment: Your pattern is entirely optional so everything will match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your RegEx should be:

```
/[a-zA-Z]+[(@!#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]{1,}/
```

Try the following way:

```js
let validateStr = (stringToValidate) => {
  var pattern = /[a-zA-Z]+[(@!#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]{1,}/;
  if ( stringToValidate && stringToValidate.length > 2 && pattern.test(stringToValidate)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};
console.log(validateStr("123$%^$"));      //false
console.log(validateStr("sdsdsdsd$%^$")); //true
console.log(validateStr("sdsdsdsd45678"));//false
console.log(validateStr("$#*()%^$"));     //false
console.log(validateStr("123434333"));    //false
```

Comment: for this case validateStr("sdsdsdsd45678") i need false to be return .

Comment: @parithiinfo, simply remove `\d` from the regex......updated the answer....please check.

Comment: @mamum its not allowed plain string , Ex: console.log (validateStr("sdsdsdsdsdsd"));// I should return true , but in ur case it returns false

Comment: @parithiinfo, you can use  `/[a-zA-Z]+([(@!#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]{1,})?/` with quantifier `?`......but in that case `validateStr("sdsdsdsd45678")` will also be true......

Comment: If i use this , console.log(validateStr("sdsdsdsd45678")); this one is also come as true .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185836/discussion-between-parithi-info-and-mamun).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to track number and special characters in your string value.

```
 function checkNumberOrSpecialCharacters(stringValue){

    if( /[^a-zA-Z\-\/]/.test( stringValue) ) {
        alert('Input is not alphabetic');
        return false;
    }
 alert('Input is alphabetic');
    return true;     
}
```