# C++ regex need to match names containing diacritics

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, diacritics

I need to match two word names like (**Johny Cash**). So I was using the regex:

```
L"^[A-Z][a-z]+\\s+[A-Z][a-z]+$"
```

However, I realized that the names may contain diacritics as well, something like **Johannes Fürnkranz**. I came across [following solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8923865/1469954) and modified my regex to:

```
L"^[A-Z].\\p{L}+\\s+[A-Z].\\p{L}+$"
```

This, assuming that the first letter in each word won't be a diacritic. However, 
 I am getting an invalid regex error. Any idea how to make it work?

Following a suggestion, I tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11255698/1469954). Problem is, the function **`test_unicode()`** never returns from me, when I am trying [here](http://cpp.sh). Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Use Boost, then you will be able to use `\p{L}`

Comment: Can't, am stuck to STL regex. :'(

Comment: Don't use Boost. Instead of `\\pL` use `[[:alpha:]]+`

Comment: Nope, doesn't work even with that..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do C++11 regular expressions work with UTF-8 strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254232/do-c11-regular-expressions-work-with-utf-8-strings)

Comment: I am trying it on cpp.sh website. What is MCVE?

Comment: There are names like `Scarlett O'Hara` or `Henry Hepburne-Scott`. Names are complicated.

Comment: Yeah of course of course. I am not trying to match all kinds of names, just a few.. :)