# JavaScript Regex to Match Boundaries of Words with diacritics

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to match in a text document, words boundaries for words having diacritics. Given a `word` token, my regex looks like

```
var wordRegex = new RegExp("\\b(" + word + ")\\b", "g");
while ((match = wordRegex.exec(text)) !== null) {
                            if (match.index > (seen.get(token) || -1)) {
                                var wordStart = match.index;
                                var wordEnd = wordStart + token.length - 1;
                                item.characterOffsetBegin = wordStart;
                                item.characterOffsetEnd = wordEnd;

                                seen.set(token, wordEnd);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
```

This works ok for ordinary words like `ciao`, `casa`, etc. But it will not works when I have in the text words like `però`, `così`, etc.

```js
const seen = new Map();
var text = "Ci son macchine nascoste e, però, nascoste male"
var tokens = text.split(/[^a-zA-Z0-9àèéìíîòóùúÀÈÉÌÍÎÒÓÙÚ]+/i)
tokens.forEach((token, tokenIndex) => {
  var item = {
    "index": (tokenIndex + 1),
    "word": token
  }
  var escaped = token.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
  var wordRegex = new RegExp("\\b(" + escaped + ")\\b", "g");
  var match = null;
  console.log(token, "---->", wordRegex)
  while ((match = wordRegex.exec(text)) !== null) {
    console.log("\t---->", match.index)
    if (match.index > (seen.get(token) || -1)) {
      var wordStart = match.index;
      var wordEnd = wordStart + token.length - 1;
      item.characterOffsetBegin = wordStart;
      item.characterOffsetEnd = wordEnd;

      seen.set(token, wordEnd);
      break;
    }
  }
})
```

You can see how while some words (like `macchine` or `nascoste`) it matches, so I get the `match.index`, for other words (like `però`) the regex does not work properly and the `match` variable is `null`:

```
macchine ----> /\b(macchine)\b/g
    ----> 7
nascoste ----> /\b(nascoste)\b/g
    ----> 16
e, ----> /\b(e\,)\b/g
però, ----> /\b(però\,)\b/g
nascoste ----> /\b(nascoste)\b/g
    ----> 16
    ----> 34
```

How to write a boundary regex that supports diacritics too then?

**[UPDATE]**
Following the approach suggested in the comments, I have used diacritics removal for each word `token` before applying the `Regex`, and then to the whole `text` like:

```
var normalizedText = removeDiacritics(text);
// for each token...
var escaped = token.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
escaped = removeDiacritics(escaped);
var wordRegex = new RegExp("\\b(" + escaped + ")\\b", "g");
var match = null;
while ((match = wordRegex.exec( normalizedText )) !== null) 
{
                             //...
```

and this time I will get the words with accents captured by the `\b` word boundaries. Of course this approach is not optimal, because the `removeDiacritics` must be applied for every token, so the best solution would be to do this once.

Comment: This might not help with your exact case, but it might be worth deburring your "word" input before executing your regex: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#deburr .

Comment: @AndrewA.thanks, that is this one: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/6018350ac10d5ce6a5b7db625140b82aeab804df/deburr.js Problem is after `deburr` to match with the original string in the text. Let me try.

Comment: @AndrewA. so the problem is of course that `deburr('però')` will become `pero`. Afterwards the Regex will not match. Here the deburr function outside lodash: https://jsfiddle.net/bcnu7km5/

Comment: I think it can work if you also deburr the regex itself, you can still see the original word with diacritics in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/beatleboy501/btefj98g/6/ . Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @AndrewA. It can works! Thanks please post your answer. If there is any answer with regex, yours is the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution we came up with in the comments to map words having diacritics to their index in the text:

```js
function removeDiacritics(text) {
  return _.deburr(text)
}

const seen = new Map();
var text = "Ci son macchine nascoste e, però, nascoste male"
var tokens = text.split(/[^a-zA-Z0-9àèéìíîòóùúÀÈÉÌÍÎÒÓÙÚ]+/i)
  var normalizedText = removeDiacritics(text)
  
tokens.forEach((token, tokenIndex) => {
  var item = {
    "index": (tokenIndex + 1),
    "word": removeDiacritics(token)
  }
  var escaped = token.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
  escaped = removeDiacritics(escaped)
  var wordRegex = new RegExp("\\b(" + escaped + ")\\b", "g");
  var match = null;
  console.log(token, "---->", wordRegex)
  while ((match = wordRegex.exec(normalizedText)) !== null) {
    console.log("\t---->", match.index)
    if (match.index > (seen.get(token) || -1)) {
      var wordStart = match.index;
      var wordEnd = wordStart + token.length - 1;
      item.characterOffsetBegin = wordStart;
      item.characterOffsetEnd = wordEnd;

      seen.set(token, wordEnd);
      break;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```